# How to initialize a const std vector in old c++?

Tags: c++, constants, stdvector, c++98

My C++ compiler identification is GNU 4.4.1

I think since c++ 11 you can initialize a vector this way:

```
const std::vector<int> myVector = {1, 2, 3};
const std::vector<int> myVector2{1, 2, 3};
```

Unfortunately, I am not using c++ 11 so myVector can just be initilized by constructor.
I need to create a vector that will never be modified. It has to be shared by differents functions within a class so it may be static as well, or even a class member.
Is there a way to make my vector be initiliazed when it gets defined in c++98, as the examples from above, or something equivalent?

Comment: Yes, and this happens to be called "dynamic initialization", which should have plenty of examples in every C++ book.

Comment: The problem in C++98 is not about your vector is whether const or non-const but the standard prevents curly-braces initialization. so try this: `std::vector<int> vi {1, 2, 3};` or `std::vector<int> vi = {1, 2, 3};`// it won't work. In those days you have to push elements.

Comment: _"Unfortunately, I am not using c++ 11 so myVector can just be initilized by constructor"_ Well, even after C++11, any object, including `std::vector`, can only be "initialized" (created) by using constructor. The C++11 `std::initializer_list` can be used only because there is a defined constructor that accepts it :)

Answer (score 7):

You can return the vector from a function:

```
std::vector<int> f();
const std::vector<int> myVector = f();
```

Alternatively, use [boost::assign::list_of](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.assign).

Answer (score 3):

@vll's answer is probably better, but you can also do:

```
int temp[] = {1, 2, 3};
const std::vector<int> myVector(temp, temp + sizeof(temp)/sizeof(temp[0]));
```

It does however create two copies instead of one, and it pollutes the namespace with the name of the array.

Answer (score 3):

You've already gotten two good answers. This is just a combination of both:

```
namespace detail {
    template<typename T, size_t N>
    size_t size(const T (&)[N]) { return N; }

    std::vector<int> vecinit() {
        int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        return std::vector<int>(arr, arr+size(arr));
    }
}

//...

const std::vector<int> myVector(detail::vecinit());
```